# Combine setting of two bits in a bitmask

Tags: php, bitmask

I have a bitmask like this:

```
$mask = 0;
$mask |= 1 << 2;
$mask |= 1 << 9;

print decbin($mask);
```

The result is `1000000100` which is what I want. I just wonder, is there a way to enable both bit 2 and 9 in a single operation? So that it looks like:

```
$mask = 0;
$mask |= 1 << (... enable 2 and 9 ...);

print decbin($mask);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, but if bitwise operations and masks are at all similar to how they are in other languages, then you can |= your number with hex 204, which is 1000000001 or 516 base 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives the same result:

```
print decbin(1 << 2 | 1 << 9);
```

- `1 << 2` results in `4`.
- `1 << 9` results in `512`.
- `512` + `4` = `516`
- `decbin(516)` = `1000000100`

Now this isn't a usual `||` statement you're doing the following:

```
101001 | 010110 = 111111
41     + 22     = 63
```

So in Laymen's terms, you're merging the values.

You could essentially put it in a function:

```
function bit_shiftlist(array $nums = [], bool $left = true){
  $ret = 0;
  foreach($nums as $value){
    $ret += $left ? 1 << $value : 1 >> $value;
  }

  return $ret;
}

$mask = bit_shiftlist([2, 9]);

var_dump($mask);       // 516
var_dump($mask ^ 512); // 4
var_dump($mask ^ 4);   // 512
var_dump($mask & 4);   // 4
var_dump($mask & 8);   // 0 - unexisting bit in both value 512 and 4.
```

Comment: Why does it give the same result? What does a single pipe do? According to [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) documentation, the `|` is an inclusive OR, which doesn't seem like it would produce the desired results...

Comment: What is stopping you from `|=`ing a given number with 0x204?

Comment: Interesting solution, @synchronizer how would did you reach 204?

Comment: @Max `0x204` is the hexadecimal representation of the value `516`.